# Flutter: hide/show widget by key dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

How can we show/hide widget inside another widget in flutter?

I have list of question which are inside list view builder I want to hide questions on user answer selection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141804/flutter-hide-show-a-widget-by-key-from-another-widget/64181007#64181007

Answer (score 1):

if you have all equations in question[] and whether to show them in show[], you could place into listbuild

```
return (bool[index] ? Card(child:Text(question[index])) : Container())
```

This returns the card in bool is true and the empty (not displayed container) otherwise.

Comment: no this is not what I want to do.. Please check this question for more details

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141804/flutter-hide-show-a-widget-by-key-from-another-widget

Answer (score 1):

(I think the other answer would do the trick too)

Another option you can consider though is using the Visibility widget to wrap the "question" widget and toggle the visible property based on a bool. To make this (or the above solution) work, you'd want to update the value of this bool using e.g. setState on the method called when,as you say, "user answer selection" happens.

Of course, if you have a more complicated application it might make more sense to use Provider for state management and wrap all of this in a Consumer.

Comment: Hey Scott, I totally get your idea. I can show you my code then I think you could answer me better I made another question but no one get the idea maybe you could help me there.

Comment: please check my code here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141804/flutter-hide-show-a-widget-by-key-from-another-widget